# Calling PLSQL stored proc from Grails service

Tags: grails, groovy, plsql, oracle11g

Need a little help with the closure part of this, and maybe a bit more. I'm trying to call a stored procedure in Oracle 11g from my Grails service.

So far:

```
import java.sql.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes

class DummyService {

def dataSource

def serviceMethod() {
}

def listPeople(){
    Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
    def resultList = []

    sql.call("BEGIN mypackage.p_get_people(?); END;",
            [Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) {cursorResults -> 

            if(cursorResults.next()) {
                results = cursorResults.getAt(1);
            }
    }
    return resultList
}
```

Alright, so this returns the first rows data, and depending on what is passed to the getAt() method, I can grab that column. Which I found here [ORACLE STORED PROCS IN GRAILS](http://www.craigburke.com/post/44771719252/oracle-stored-procs-in-grails)

What I really want is to return the result set and put it into a list, I'm just not sure how to do it.

When I try `{cursorResults -> println cursorResults}` it throws an error

```
Message: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement with Address: "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement@...."is closed
```

Running this procedure directly in Oracle there is 457 rows in the cursor, if that helps at all.

Edit 1:
Response to dmahapatro, this is the NPE

```
| Error 2013-05-07 14:16:05,123 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /testapp/messages/list
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
Line | Method
->>  15 | list     in testapp.MessagesController$$EO5AzzAw
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

And right now line 15 is simply  `println dummyService.listPeople()`

Comment: What is `affiliateList` in `listPeople()`?

Comment: same list as peopleList, I was changing names around

Comment: Have you used `eachRow` as mentioned in the answer below?

Comment: Yes. Looks like `{cursorResults -> cursorResults.eachRow{result -> resultList << result}`

Comment: I am not sure about the NPE in the code block unless I am able to see it fully. You can also try using `sql.eachRow` instead of `sql.call`. `sql.eachRow` calls the closure for each row. See my edit for a sample.

Answer (score 1):

`sql.call` results to `GroovyResultSet`. You should be able to do an `eachRow` on the resultset and push it to the list.

```
def listPeople(){
    Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
    def resultList = []

    sql.call("BEGIN mypackage.p_get_people(?); END;",
            [Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) {cursorResults -> 
            cursorResults.eachRow{result ->
                resultList << result
            }
    }
    return resultList
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively using `sql.eachRow`

```
    sql.eachRow("BEGIN mypackage.p_get_people(?); END;",
            [Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) {row -> 
                resultList << row
    }
```

Comment: Which line? You said you already have the `cursorResults` populated? Can I see the exception?

Comment: Have a look at the last few lines from the same post you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that did work for me is this:

```
def array = []
sql.call("begin SCHEMA.PKG_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME(${personId},${Sql.resultSet OracleTypes.CURSOR}); end;") 
            {rset -> 
                rset.eachRow(){                        
                    array.add(["NAME":it.getString("TABLE_COLUMN_NAME"),"DESC":it.getString("TABLE_COLUMN_DESC")])
                }
            }
```

When I wasn't using it.getString("TABLE_COLUMN_NAME") it'd threw me a NULL error on everything I try to "println"