# Groovy SQL PLSQL call java.sql.SQLEception: "oracle.jdbc.driver" is closed

Tags: groovy, plsql

Trying to call a PLSQL stored procedure and running into this error that I cannot get around.
The stored procedure takes 5 parameters and returns a cursor and an error message. All parameters are varchar2, and the error message is a varchar2.

The method:

```
List fetchEmployees(){
    List employeeList = []
    Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
    sql.call("BEGIN package.p_get_employees(?,?,?,?,?,?,?); END;",
        [code1,code2,code3,code4,code5,Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR),Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.VARCHAR)])
    {cursorResults ->

                while(cursorResults.next()){
                    def person = new Person()
                    person.setEmail(cursorResults.getAt(1))
                    person.setNetid(cursorResults.getAt(0))
                    employeeList.add(person)
                }
    }

    return employeeList
}
```

And when I try and run through this, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement with address: "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement@e76514" is closed.
...
```

Comment: Is it no way related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427270/calling-plsql-stored-proc-from-grails-service) question you asked earlier?

Comment: No, that question had no parameters. And all the examples I can find don't use parameters.

Comment: How about visiting the API http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html itself?

Comment: Thank you, I will spend some quality time in the docs and see if I can work it out myself.

Comment: Have a look at `call(java.lang.String, java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure)` which shows an example of your use case.