# How to get return value from stored procedure with output parameter in Grails?

Tags: oracle, grails, stored-procedures, intellij-idea

I have a stored procedure that has an output parameter which is a cursor

Here's the code for the stored procedure I currently use, I don't know how to get the return value

```
def kf_fpy
sql.call("{call calfpy(?,?,?,?,?)}",[workcenter,product,stattime,endtime,Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)])

{
                cursorResults ->
                   cursorResults.eachRow() {
                        x ->
                          kf_fpy = x.getAt('kf_fpy')//ERROR OCCURED
                   }
}
```

And I got an error "Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate $Proxy11.toString()"

**Stored Procedure：**

```
PROCEDURE CALFPY(workcenter in varchar2,produ in varchar2,stdt in varchar2,etdt in varchar2,p_out out pkg_package.type_cursor)
```

**PKG_PACKAGE:**

```
create or replace
package pkg_package 
as 
type type_cursor is ref cursor; 
type type_record is record 
( 
kf_ws varchar2(20), 
kf_fpy number,
kf_tfpy number,
kf_pro varchar2(200)

); 
end;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N3FQ.jpg)

Comment: Could you paste stacktrace with more details, please? Which property and in which line of your code is missing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I'm trying to do is creating a webservice, so I can call the oracle stored procedure in the webservice,but the return value of the procedure is a CURSOR,I have no idea how to get the return value exactly,can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this solution](http://www.craigburke.com/2011/05/13/oracle-stored-procs-in-grails.html):

**Procedure**:

```
create or replace procedure GRAILS_EXAMPLE
(
  v_name IN VARCHAR2,
  ref_cur1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
begin

  OPEN ref_cur1 FOR
  SELECT UPPER(v_name) AS UPPER_NAME
  FROM DUAL;

end GRAILS_EXAMPLE;
```

**Controller which calls procedure**:

```
    String upperName;
    sql.call("BEGIN GRAILS_EXAMPLE(?,?); END;",
            [params.name, Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) {cursorResults ->

            if (cursorResults.next()) {
                 upperName = cursorResults.getAt('UPPER_NAME');
            }

    }
```

> If you need to get at a field that isn't properly aliased in your proc
>   you can still access it by its index. For example the follow would
>   also work in the above controller:
>
> ```
> upperName = cursorResults.getAt(0)
> ```

If you need more values from procedure check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27173650/2166188).

Comment: Thank You Very Much，I hav solved it with your help,and you are right the field isn't properly aliased in the proc,but getAt(0) is still work,
Thank you again!